# iCloudからダウンロードしたRealmのバックアップを用いてデータの復元

Tags: swift, realm

**実現したいこと**
RealmのオブジェクトをiCloudにアップロード、ダウンロードすることにより、スマホを紛失してもデータを復元ができるアプリデータの永続化対応

**発生している問題**
iCloudからダウンロードしたRealmのデータをアプリで見ようとするとエラーが発生します。

**詳細なOK処理、NG処理**

① iCloudにアップロード、アプリそのままで、iCloudからデータをダウンロード、データをアプリで見る　→　OK
② iCloudにアップロード、アプリをBuildでインストール、iCloudからデータをダウンロード、データをアプリで見る　→　OK
③ iCloudにアップロード、アプリを手で削除してBuildでインストール、iCloudからデータをダウンロード、データをアプリで見る　→　NG

③が機種変をイメージしています。

今回の件はiCloudは関係なく、外部から取り込んだRealmデータを反映する箇所に問題があると思って、色々調査しましたが、わかりませんでした。
お忙しいところ恐れ入りますが、どなたか、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=2 "Unable to open a realm at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BA8E4840-F570-4AE0-BBA0-EF3D9B8936B0/Documents/default.realm': Realm file has bad size (181) Path:Exception backtrace:
0   Realm                               0x00000001064c7e10 _ZN5realm15InvalidDatabaseC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_ + 60
1   Realm                               0x0000000106491c74 _ZN5realm9SlabAlloc15validate_headerEPKcmRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEE + 864
2   Realm                               0x0000000106490f28 _ZN5realm9SlabAlloc11attach_fileERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEERNS0_6ConfigE + 708
```

**ソースコード**

Class1

```
    private var _realm:Realm? = nil
    private var realm:Realm {
        get {
            if let realm2 = _realm {
                return realm2
            } else {
                let realm2 = try! Realm()     // ※※※ エラー発生位置 ※※※
                _realm = realm2
                return realm2
            }
        }
    }
```

Class2

```
    private let _fileManager = FileManager.default
    /// バックアップフォルダURL
    private var backupFolderUrl: URL{
        get {
            return _fileManager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)!
                .appendingPathComponent("BackUp")
        }}
    /// バックアップファイル名（前部）
    private let mBackupFileNamePre = "default.realm_bk_"
    
    /// Realmのデータを復元
    func restoreRealm() {
        guard let realmURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL else {
            print("Realmのファイルパスが取得できませんでした。")
            return
        }
        // バックアップファイルの有無チェック
        let (exists, files) = isBackupFileExists()
        if exists {
            do {
                let config = Realm.Configuration()
                // 既存Realmファイル削除
                let realmURLs = [
                    realmURL,
                    realmURL.appendingPathExtension("lock"),
                    realmURL.appendingPathExtension("note"),
                    realmURL.appendingPathExtension("management")
                ]
                for URL in realmURLs {
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL)
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                // バックアップファイルをRealmの位置にコピー
                try _fileManager.copyItem(at: backupFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent(files[files.count - 1]),
                                          to: realmURL)
                Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
                abort()   // 既存のRealmを開放させるため
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    /// バックアップデータ作成処理
    /// RealmのデータをiCloudにコピー
    func backup() {
        do {
            /// iCloudにフォルダ作成
            if _fileManager.fileExists(atPath: backupFolderUrl.path) {
            } else {
                try _fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: backupFolderUrl.path, withIntermediateDirectories: false)
            }

            // 既存バックアップファイル（iCloud）の削除
            deleteBackup()
            // バックアップ作成先（iCloud）
            let fileName = mBackupFileNamePre + ""   // 日付
            let fileUrl = backupFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            // バックアップ作成
            try backupRealm(backupFileUrl: fileUrl)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    /// Realmのデータファイルを指定ファイル名（フルパス）にコピー
    /// - Parameter backupFileUrl: 指定ファイル名（フルパス）URL
    private func backupRealm(backupFileUrl: URL) throws {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            realm.beginWrite()
            try realm.writeCopy(toFile: backupFileUrl)
            realm.cancelWrite()
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
    
    /// バックアップファイル削除
    func deleteBackup() {
        let (exists, files) = isBackupFileExists()
        if exists {
            do {
                for file in files {
                    try _fileManager.removeItem(at: backupFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent(file))
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// バックアップフォルダにバックアップファイルがあるか、ある場合、そのファイル名を取得
    /// - Returns: バックアップファイルの有無、そのファイル名
    private func isBackupFileExists() -> (Bool, [String]) {
        var exists = false
        var files: [String] = []
        var allFiles: [String] = []
        // バックアップフォルダのファイル取得
        do {
            allFiles = try _fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: backupFolderUrl.path)
        } catch {
            return (exists, files)
        }
        // バックアップファイル名を選別
        for file in allFiles {
            if file.contains(mBackupFileNamePre) {
                exists = true
                files.append(file)
            }
        }
        return (exists, files)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。
事前に、
FileManager.default.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at:)
にて、対象ファイルと同期をとることで、正常にRealmのデータを復元できました。